# INNER JOIN? Two table joining of userid with other userid

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue coming up with an SQL statement. CANNOT get my head around multi table interaction in MySQL.

So I have 2 tables:

This is my `users` table:
[image: This is my users table.]

This is my `messages` table:
[image: This is my messages table.]

What I want to do is generate a table that basically shows:

IF I AM USER 1

`Daniel - Melbourne University`

I only want his name to appear if I have sent a message to him, or received one from him.

Totally lost on how to do this, any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways.

```
SELECT
  users.*
FROM
  users
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT messages_senderid   AS user_id FROM messages WHERE messages_receiverid = 1
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT messages_receiverid AS user_id FROM messages WHERE messages_senderid   = 1
)
  contacts
    ON users.users_userid = contacts.user_id
```

Or perhaps...

```
SELECT
  users.*
FROM
  users
WHERE
     EXISTS (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE messages_senderid   = users.users_userid AND messages_receiverid = 1)
  OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE messages_receiverid = users.users_userid AND messages_senderid   = 1)
```

Comment: . . Just so you know, the `select distinct` is redundant when used with `union`.  The `union` will remove duplicates anyway.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't work it out myself! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users_name,users_university
FROM users
WHERE users_userid IN (SELECT messages_senderid 
                       FROM messages WHERE messages_receiverid=1)
     OR  users_userid IN (SELECT messages_receiverid 
                       FROM messages WHERE messages_senderid=1)
```

Another method

```
SELECT users_name,users_university
FROM users
WHERE users_userid IN ( SELECT 
                              CASE WHEN messages_receiverid=1 THEN messages_senderid
                                   WHEN messages_senderid=1 THEN messages_receiverid
                              END
                        FROM messages
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select u.users_name, u.users_university
from users u
where u.users_usersid in(select m.messages_receiverid
from messages m
where m.messages_senderid=1
union
select m.messages_senderid
from messages m
where m.messages_receiverid=1)
```

Comment: `u.users_userid=1 and u.users_userid=m.messages_senderid` => `1=m.messages_senderid`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `:user_id` is a given parameter (in your example: 1), you can try this:

```
select concat(users_name, ' - ', users_university, ' University') 
from users u 
where exists (select 1 
              from messages 
              where messages_receiverid = :user_id 
                    or messages_senderid = :user_id)
```

Combining `exists` and `select 1` in a subquery is a fast solution in such cases.

Comment: AFAIK the @notation isn't MySQL compatible *(admittedly a minor point)*.  Also `WHERE a=1 OR b=1` is often compromised by the lack of a single index that can fulfil the search condition; which is why other answers use a UNION of two queries, as each query can then use a separate index - Each potentially completing much quicker than the single `OR` query.

Comment: To "@" notation - I don't use MySQL, so I googled "mysql parameter" phrase, and the page with MySQL Connector/NET came up and there the "@" notation is valid. So it depends on provider, but after some research I know I should've use :notation. And when it comes to OR vs UNION - I understand your point, but I am not sure if in such case it would be an improvement.

Comment: With the `OR` logic you often get a full table scan.  With the `UNION` logic combined with two indexes you get two index-seeks and a merge.  The larger the data-set the more pronounced the difference.  And the smaller the faction of the total table that is relevant, the more pronounced the difference.